# SharePoint Modern Library - Power Automate notification email - 6 Months after Created date

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, power-automate, reminder, email-notification

I have a basic SharePoint Online library in which I need to send a notification email 6 months (184 days) from the Created Date.  It's a reminder to an Item's submitter that they're document needs to be updated.  I think Power Automate would be the best option, but i'm not sure how to set it up.  I selected the template to send notification when an item is uploaded.  I assumed I'd create a condition based off the Created field, but I'm not sure what the next expression would be.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Theoretically, if you used the triggers for when an item/file is created, you would then use a Delay action to delay for six months, and then you would send the email. This issue with this technique is that a flow run cannot last more than thirty days.

The way I would handle this task is to use a scheduled flow (i.e. a timer trigger). I would run the flow once a day and query the list/library for items created six months ago, and send email notifications for the items that were found.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  I like the timer trigger idea, though I'm not very familiar with that function in PA.  How would I go about setting that up to send an email after 184 days or so?

Comment: This article shows how to create a flow that runs on a schedule:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/run-scheduled-tasks

Comment: This blog post shows how to get items from SharePoint filtering on the created date: https://tomriha.com/how-to-filter-sharepoint-items-based-on-created-date-in-power-automate/